# Determining the phase portrait - notational uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm given that $A = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\ 
0 & \mu
\end{bmatrix}$ and the IVP $\begin{cases} \dot{X} = AX\\ X(0) = X_0 \end{cases}$.

Solving this is easy - the solution is $X(t) = e^{tA}X_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{t\lambda} & 0 \\ 
0 & e^{t\mu}
\end{bmatrix}X_0$.

I follow the material that I'm reading fine until here. But in the very next line it writes
$$X_2 = CX_1^{\frac{\mu}{\lambda}}.$$
Where does this come from? I'm guessing that the $X_1, X_2$ comes from taking $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ 
X_2
\end{bmatrix}$, but I still don't know how we get the above equation.

For the sake of context, we then proceed to draw the phase portrait for various cases of $\lambda, \mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, $X_1, X_2$ are the components of $X$:

$$ \left( \frac{X_1(t)}{X_1(0)} \right)^{1/\lambda} = e^t = \left( \frac{X_2(t)}{X_2(0)} \right)^{1/\mu}. $$

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!