# Playing cupid (turning an uncoupled equation into a coupled one)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is in the same vein as my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779388/determining-the-phase-portrait-notational-uncertainty).

I'm given that $A = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & \varepsilon \\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}$ and the IVP $\begin{cases} \dot{X} = AX\\ X(0) = X_0 \end{cases}$.

Solving this is easy - the solution is $X(t) = e^{tA}X_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{t\lambda} & \varepsilon te^{t\lambda} \\ 
0 & e^{t\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}X_0$.

Taking $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ 
X_2
\end{bmatrix}$, we somehow manage to get that $$X_2 = \frac{-\lambda}{\varepsilon}X_1.$$
I tried following the approach the answer to my previous question gave, but I can't get anywhere with it. How do we get the above equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the attempted approach, or even starting idea, is completely wrong.

Notice that the IVP has a repeated real eigenvalue. To draw the phase portrait, it would be nice to know the equation of the [nullclines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullcline). So we need to set $\dot{X}_1 = 0$ and $\dot{X}_2 = 0$.

It immediately follows that our nullclines have equation $X_2 = \dfrac{-\lambda}{\varepsilon}X_1$ and $X_2 = 0$.